# Not an array reference message is thrown when using XML:Simple

Tags: perl

I am new to perl and trying to parse XML using XML:Simple

My xml is

```
<suite suiteId="45" instanceId="3485">
   <project>Test project</project>
   <testcase id="2346" name="abc" suite="TEst1" priority="1" severity="1" owner="domain" category="BAT" timeout="10">
    <description>Checking Test1</description>
    <testExecTimeInMins>2</testExecTimeInMins>
    <status>Failed</status>
    <testServer id="86" name="host1" ip="1.2.3.4" platform="Linux" database="MySQL" buildNo="" />
    <error></error>
  </testcase>
  <testcase id="2346456" name="abc123" suite="TEst2" priority="1" severity="1" owner="domain" category="BAT" timeout="10">
    <description>Checking Test2</description>
    <testExecTimeInMins>6</testExecTimeInMins>
    <status>Passed</status>
    <testServer id="86" name="host1" ip="1.2.3.4" platform="Linux" database="MySQL" buildNo="" />
    <error />
  </testcase>
 </suite>
```

How do I get the values of testcase id, name, suite?
How to get the values for testServer, id, name?

I tried to access it as shown below but it throws "Not an Array reference at"

```
$XMLData = XMLin($targetFile);


foreach my $testcases (@{$XMLData->{testcase}}){
    $logger->info("$testcases->{id}");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you examine the actual data that is coming out of `XMLin`, you would see that you don't have an array reference (just like the error message states), but instead have a hashref that is keyed on the name of the testcase:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 

use Data::Dumper; 
use XML::Simple; 

my $xml = XMLin("/Users/mcmillhj/temp.xml");

print Dumper $xml;

__DATA__
{
          'instanceId' => '3485',
          'project' => 'Test project',
          'testcase' => {
                        'abc123' => {
                                    'owner' => 'domain',
                                    'priority' => '1',
                                    'status' => 'Passed',
                                    'suite' => 'TEst2',
                                    'testExecTimeInMins' => '6',
                                    'description' => 'Checking Test2',
                                    'timeout' => '10',
                                    'error' => {},
                                    'category' => 'BAT',
                                    'id' => '2346456',
                                    'severity' => '1',
                                    'testServer' => {
                                                    'database' => 'MySQL',
                                                    'buildNo' => '',
                                                    'ip' => '1.2.3.4',
                                                    'name' => 'host1',
                                                    'platform' => 'Linux',
                                                    'id' => '86'
                                                  }
                                  },
                        'abc' => {
                                 'owner' => 'domain',
                                 'priority' => '1',
                                 'status' => 'Failed',
                                 'suite' => 'TEst1',
                                 'testExecTimeInMins' => '2',
                                 'description' => 'Checking Test1',
                                 'timeout' => '10',
                                 'error' => {},
                                 'category' => 'BAT',
                                 'id' => '2346',
                                 'severity' => '1',
                                 'testServer' => {
                                                 'database' => 'MySQL',
                                                 'buildNo' => '',
                                                 'ip' => '1.2.3.4',
                                                 'name' => 'host1',
                                                 'platform' => 'Linux',
                                                 'id' => '86'
                                               }
                               }
                      },
          'suiteId' => '45'
        };
```

To get all testcases, you just need to iterate over the keys:

```
foreach my $testcasename ( keys %{ $XMLData->{testcase} } ){
    $logger->info($XMLdata->{testcase}->{$testcasename}->{id});
}
```